# Name of individual arrays created in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have created 5 arrays using this code:

```
for (int i=1; i<6; i++){
  Array[] taxBracket = new Array[4];
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(taxBracket));
}
```

It gives me the following out put:

```
[null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null] 
[null, null, null, null] 
[null, null, null, null] 
[null, null, null, null]
```

Which is fine, but how can i now work on any one of the arrays individually?
For lets say calling `toString()` method of the first array.
I want to do something like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(taxBracket1);
```

or

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(taxBracket2);
```

Comment: Why are you using the `Array` class and not `type[][]`?

Comment: I want it to be a single dimension array.

Comment: but now, when i think about it, 2 dimensional array may make it easier for me to access individual line of data.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would create an array of the *type* that you want to act on.

For example; if you're using an array of `BigDecimal`s to represent a single `taxBracket`, then you would declare it as:

```
final BigDecimal[][] taxBrackets = new BigDecimal[5][2];
taxBrackets[0][0] = new BigDecimal("0");
taxBrackets[0][1] = new BigDecimal("12500");

taxBrackets[1][0] = new BigDecimal("12500.01");
// ... etc.
```

Using the type `Array` directly is probably not what you want to do.

---

> I want it to be a single dimension array.

Then presumably you have some type which represents a singular `TaxBracket` (be it an `enum`, `double`, etc.).  In which case you're going to want an array of that type:

```
final TaxBracket[] brackets = new TaxBracket[5];
brackets[0] = new TaxBracket(/* Parameters to construct or particular enum value */);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of scope, none of those arrays will exist outside of the for loop.  You need to declare a map of array outside of the for loop to keep them in scope and accessible otherwise they wont exist.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You could access contents of an array via index. As for your code, take out taxBracket out of the loop as it will be reinitialized per iteration and it will not exist outside the loop. You could create 2d array for your problem. However, I would highly recommend that you use HashMap instead.

For the 2d array implementation, what you could do is:

```
int [][] taxBracket = new int[5][4]
```

Then you could access its content by:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < taxBracket.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < taxBracket[i].length; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print(taxBracket[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

If you want to push through in accessing via names, use HashMap or Map. I could provide you a sample code of Maps if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `taxBracket` is a reference to an array and therefore reference only the last array created in the loop. The other arrays are lost and will be discarded by Java garbage collection. Also note that since `taxBracket` was declared inside the loop scope it will not exist after the loop ends.

As @Andrew Li suggested I would use a 2D array. If you want to used names for the first dimension you can use constants:

```
final int BRACKET1 = 0, BRACKET2 = 1, BRACKET3 = 2;   // name the brackets here
final int ROWS = 5;
final int COLS = 10;

int[][] taxArray = new int[ROWS][COLS];   // this is your array

// now you can print the way you wanted
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(taxArray[BRACKET2]));
```